# How to get checked items in gsp/groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I have code similar to as mentioned below.

```
<g:each in="${Accounts}" var="account">
<li>
    <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${account.id}" />
    <g:hiddenField name="memberId" value="${account.memberId}" />
    <g:hiddenField name="accountType" value="${account.type}" />
    <label><input type="checkbox" />${member.name}</label>
</li>
</g:each>
```

In my groovy controller, I am trying to access the list of accounts checked by the user.

Could somebody help me how I can get the checked items in my controller 'params'

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GSP:

```
  <g:form controller="some" action="updateAccountIds">
    <g:each in="${Accounts}" var="account">
       ...
      <label><g:checkBox name="checkedAccount" value="${account.id}"/>${member.name}</label>
    </g:each>
  </g:form>
```

Controller action:

```
def updateAccountIds(){
   def ids = params.list 'checkedAccount'
   log.info "checked = $ids"

   doOtherStuff()
}
```